# How do I connect RDS postgres through command line?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I set up a Postgresql RDS instance and I am able to connect via Pgadmin but how do I connect to RDS through command line?

I tried with below but it throws me error (command not found psql)

```
psql --host=2vukdlfgwf.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=postgres --password --dbname=postgres
```

Comment: Please, never say "an error", **always** show us what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

The `command not found: psql` problem indicates that the `psql` client is either missing from your system's `PATH` or is not installed. Make sure `psql` is present in your `PATH` to fix this. When executing the command, you can also include the complete path to the psql programme. If you are aware of where psql is located, you can use the command line to connect to your Amazon RDS PostgreSQL instance by invoking it with the entire path.